Time in Schwarzschild coordinates
After reading that the Schwarzschild solution is static, i.e., it is independent of time, I am wondering in what frame. Changing frames means mixing space and time through coordinate transformations. So in which frame the Schwarzschild solution is static?

The Schwarzschild solution is static inside the horizon as well, because this solution is an unphysical eternal abstraction. The Schwarzschild singularity is an infinitely long spacelike line along the $t$ coordinate. If we take Schwarzschild slices $t=const$ at different values of $t$, all these slices would be identical. Note that these slices are not physical timeslices, because $t$ is spacelike inside the horizon. Regardless, the slices don’t depend on the Schwarzschild time, so the solution is static inside and outside. This is very different in a real physical star collapse.

The Schwartzschild solution looks time-independent in the Schwartzschild coordinates (for the exterior solution) as the metric components are fully time-independent.
As you mentioned time-independence very much seems like a frame-dependent notion, however, a spacetime being static is actually a frame-independent statement. Rather we formally define a static spacetime to be a spacetime with a global timelike Killing vectorfield that is hypersurface orthogonal.
This statement is independent of the choice of frame and can intuitively be seen as follows:

A timelike Killing field: This will define what we mean by 'time' i.e. it provides a sort of natural clock on the spacetime

global: This clock should be defined everywhere.

Hypersurface orthogonal:
So this vector field defines a time coordinate. However, this still leaves us with a choice of space coordinates. The statement of orthogonality is that on each such leaf the coordinates can be chosen identically in a smooth fashion i.e. the coordinates are independent of time on each slice.


So how is this related to the coordinate statement of time-independence? It is exactly these coordinates that we define above in which the metric (locally) takes the form $ds^2 = -\beta(x) dt^2 + h_{ij}(x) dx^i dx^j $ where in these coordinates the Killing vector takes the simple form $\partial_t$.
EDIT: To reiterate a point brought up in the comments, this discussion is only valid outside the horizon as the vector $\partial_t$ becomes spacelike in the interior.

Good answer, +1. One very minor recommendation would be to not refer to my answer at all. Yours stands on its own quite well and now your answer is above mine (as it deserves to be IMO)

Small caveat, you should restrict your domain to outside the event horizon. When you cross the event horizon, the radial and time coordinate switch, so your Killing field becomes space-like, so technically your metric acquires time dependence.

I agree that's why I specified the exterior solution at the beginning but should probably be mentioned more directly

The exterior disclaimer is unnecessary. The solution is static inside and outside along the Schwarzschild time coordinate $t$. It doesn’t matter that $t$ is spacelike inside, because we are not analyzing the solution in different coordinates inside snd outside. All Schwarzschild $t=const$ slices are identical regardless of the value of $t$. In other words, the metric coefficients don’t depend on the Schwarzschild time $t$, hence the solution is static in the Schwarzschild coordinates and therefore in any coordinates.

@safesphere By the formal definition of static, it does matter as this definition requires a global timelike killing vector field. Thus the argument above is invalid in this region as $\partial_t$ is no longer a timelike vector field. I agree that the slices are still 'time' indep. where time is defined as the coordinate t however that no longer refers to a static spacetime. Indeed the failure stems from the coordinates only covering either the exterior or interior patch due to the coord. singularity so no statements on global killing vectorfields for both regions simultaneously can be made

@ThomasTappeiner Perhaps, but “the formal definition” is just something that someone has dreamed up based on certain views and assumptions that don’t always or necessarily reflect the physical meaning of the phenomena. My comment above was not based on “the formal definition”, but on the fact that nothing ever changes anywhere in the Schwarzschild spacetime in the coordinates of a remote observer. (I probably should not have said “in any coordinates” on the last line, point taken, thanks).

A static spacetime has a global, irrotational, timelike Killing vector. The metric is independent of time in any frame that uses that Killing vector as the frame's time vector, $\partial_t$. The manifold is still static even in frames where the metric is not independent of the time coordinate, because the existence of the timelike Killing vector is independent of the coordinates.
